# To show slf4j logs on prompt as they appear

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-boot, slf4j

I am working with AngularJs spring boot application. For logging purpose sjf4j has been used. It working fine and writing logs to log file.

Now I want logs of some process to be shown on a prompt i.e. a model on my html page. The logs are continuously updating and same time I need to show them on my prompt.

```
public boolean myMethod() {
        log.debug("My method process start.");
        ..............
        ...............
        ................
        ..................
        ........
        log.debug("Mid of process.");
        ............
        ...........
        log.debug("My method process end.");  }
```

I need to write all these messages of debug to log file and also need to show on prompt. I can store these string of messages in some storage like hash table, but that will not be convenient to read at other end and also regular update in this and getting values incrementally may be cumbersome with hash.

What can be the best way to return the values of logs to front end angular JS, html pages as they occur in my resource Java back-end class in process.